# mysqld status shows stopped but it actually runs

Tags: mysql, centos6

I use CentOS6 Hortonworks Sandbox.
When I run:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# service mysqld stop
```

it stopped and I checked with:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# service mysqld status
mysqld is stopped
```

Everything is fine is up to now. But when I tried to start with this:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

And I checked again:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# service mysqld status
mysqld is stopped
```

But strange thing is happening now:

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5486
Server version: 5.6.39 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I don't understand how this can happen?

Answer (score 0):

​I solved it. I learned mysqld pid with:

```
top
```

​then killed it

```
kill 24678
```

​I started mysqld :

```
service start mysqld
```

The problem was:

```
service mysqld stop
```

​couldn't stop mysqld.